# Symfony 2.0.4 - Bad credentials at login

Tags: symfony

I have problem wtih login. I use correct login in the table in database. Here is [my controller](http://pastebin.com/EbW5GTju).

My `security.yml`:

```
security:
  encoders:
    My\HelloBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm: sha512 
        encode_as_base64: true 
        iterations: 10 

  role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

  providers:
    users_db:
        entity: { class: My\HelloBundle\Entity\User, property: email }

  firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
        #http_basic:
        #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

  access_control:
    #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
    #- { path: ^/_internal, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
```

My Entity is too long to paste here, so I put it on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/yxpQE5fh)

I have problem during login, but it works fine with registration (passwords got salted and saves fine to the database).

This is the error message:

```
exception 'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException' with message 'Bad credentials' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mgr\4_symfony\vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\UserAuthenticationProvider.php:83 Stack trace: #0
```

Please help me.
Regards.

Comment: As a first thought. Why don't you use FOSUserBundle ( https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle ), which is made for dealing with user login/signup processes in Symfony?

Comment: You don't use the FOSUserBundle on purpose or because you don't know it?

Comment: I write master thesis and I not use package

Answer (score 0):

I notice a couple of issues:

You are not using the Symfony provided encoder, basically your encoder configuration in the security.yml is being ignored, you can change the code (HelloController starting at line 70) to encode your password to:

```
$factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');

$encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
$password = $encoder->encodePassword($user->getPassword(),
                            $user->getSalt());
$user->setPassword($password);
```

I used that stub from the [Symfony Security documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#encoding-the-user-s-password) and worked for me.

I don't think the user is being persisted in any part of the provided code, maybe adding this after `$user->setPassword($password);`?

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```

Check that the user is being inserted in your database and that the password and the salt are present, the authentication will fail if the salt is not persisted.

Also, I haven't used sha512 but I think you're not creating the salt properly, try instead:

```
$user->setSalt(hash('sha512', $user->getPassword()));
```